# Отправка данных формы аяксом yii2

Tags: yii2

Здравствуйте. Мне нужно отправить данные моей формы аяксом на yii2. Создал модель, создал экшен, как построить саму форму, не могу найти. В первом yii использовал такой удобный хелпер, как ajaxSubmitButton. Как сделать аяксовую отправку данных формы в yii2? Если есть материал, дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/1350
Вот тут гляньте. В обсуждении есть решение вашего вопроса.

Там приводится такого рода пример.

```
    $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id' => 'contact-form',
'withAjaxSubmit' => true,

'afterSubmit' => new JsExpression('function($form, data, status, xhr) {
console.log("afterSubmit");
console.log(data);
console.log(status);
console.log(xhr);
}'),

'afterSuccessfulSubmit' => new JsExpression('function($form, data, status, xhr) {
console.log("afterSuccessfulSubmit");
console.log(data);
console.log(status);
console.log(xhr);
}'),

'afterUnsuccessfulSubmit' => new JsExpression('function($form, data, status, xhr) {
console.log("afterUnsuccessfulSubmit");
console.log(data);
console.log(status);
console.log(xhr);
}'),

'immediatelyAfterSubmit' => new JsExpression('function($form) {
console.log("immediatelyAfterSubmit");
}'),

'ajaxData' => [ 'ordering' => new JsExpression('2*2') ],
]);
```

Я думаю не стоит объяснять, что здесь каждый пункт означает.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать выдержку ответа здесь, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника. Ответы-ссылки могут стать недействительными в случае изменения страницы, на которую дана ссылка.

Comment: принято. исправлюсь )

Comment: За что минусуем? Выложил жеж решение вопроса )

Answer (score 1):

Могу предложить такой вариант. Делаете обычную форму без аякса. а на сабмит формы уже вешаете аякс.

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var form = $(this);
$.post(form.attr('action'), form.serialize, function(data){
console.log(data);
});
});
```

Answer (score -1):

можно еще с помощью PJax сделать http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-pjax.html

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Поясните, на чем основано ваше утверждение? Добавьте в ответ минимальный необходимый пример решения (информацию по ссылке могут удалить и ответ потеряет ценность).